# ReferenceError for Javascript within Web user control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I've had similar problems in the fast, but always been able to circumvent them by putting the script in the main page. This time, however, the script needs to be in the web user control.

But for some reason, the script does not get loaded, and Firefox's console tells me `ReferenceError: deleteSystemMessage` is not defined and I just don't understand why.

This is basically the setup inside the web user control:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    

    function deleteSystemMessage() {
        $(".bubbletext").val(callWebMethod("EventCalendar.aspx/GetTodaysSystemMessage", {}));
        hideActiveToolTip();
    }

    function hideActiveToolTip() {
        var tooltip = Telerik.Web.UI.RadToolTip.getCurrent();
        if (tooltip) {
            tooltip.hide();
        }
    }

</script>
```

Nevermind that the code seems to do things it doesn't advertise. The page isn't at all aware of the existence of the script.

This web user control is located within a RadToolTipManager and can execute Javascript on the main page, as well as handle normal server side click events.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When the user control is loaded via AJAX (http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/tooltip/examples/targetcontrolsandajax/defaultcs.aspx?product=tooltip), you must register your scripts the way MS AJAX requires you to, so the browser will parse them. This will happen without the tootlip manager as well.

To summarize, regiseter your script via the **ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock Method** (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock(v=vs.110).aspx)